# android listview or scrollview: for a form with dynamic number of fields

Tags: android, android-listview, android-scrollview

Let's say I need to take names of movies the person likes. I don't know how many he likes so I want to present him with just one text field. He can click a button and add more fields to fill. I can use `ScrollView` of course but should I think about using a `ListView`? If so, I can't seem to understand how. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
  public class TestingActivity extends ListActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

EditText value;
    Button insert;

    ArrayList<String> data=new ArrayList<String>();
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);



          insert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
          value=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.value);
          insert.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                data.add(value.getText().toString());
                getListView().setAdapter(new  ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data));

                    }
        });
          getListView().setAdapter(new  ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data));

    }

        }
```

xml is:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/value"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="insert" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollingCache="false" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Better, add edittext dynamically inside scrollview, onclick of a button.

Comment: ListViews are reusing resources more efficient than a ScrollView. This will result in bad performance (that nobody wants ;))

Comment: @Raghu Nagaraju Yeah right for lesser data we can use Scroll View instead of Listview..I agree!!!!

Comment: I'm also opting for EditText inside ScrollView. If you use ListView you will have a lot of problems related to focus.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement an own [BaseAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html) that uses EditText-Views to let people enter data.
[Here's](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html) how to implement a good Adapter.

If the Button is getting clicked you can just add another entry in a List that is used to add another View to your Adapter.

Comment: see the edit ;) there are good examples from Google in the API demos.

Comment: It is a mechanism to get a View that got defined in XML.

Comment: I don't understand what is the role of `holder` there? It's only used in a function so it's a local variable. it's also not leaving any side-effect on `convertView`.

Comment: The holder is used to improve the ListView's performance by setting a tag for the ConvertView. The views don't always need to be reinitialized and this saves some time.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12786/discussion-between-prongs-and-tim-messerschmidt)